# ¿Management Studio para SQL Server en edición Express incluye el Profiler? En caso que no, ¿qué alternativas hay?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

He leído que el Management Studio edición Express para la versión 2016 viene con un mayor conjunto de herramientas a comparación de las ediciones anteriores, ¿eso incluye el profiler? En caso que no, ¿qué alternativas hay para evaluar los cuellos de botella de mis procesos de base de datos que trabajan con SQL Server?

Comment: Para quienes voten a cerrar, les adelanto que esta pregunta es válida para el sitio.

Comment: Acabo de instalar SQLServer Express Edition y efectivamente el Managament Studio viene completo, incluye la herramieta de SQL Profiler.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Quizás es sólo mi opinión pero una pregunta que se puede responder con un "sí" o "no", sin necesidad de más explicación, no es válida para el sitio.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro la respuesta sí puede proveer una explicación, sobretodo en el caso que la respuesta sea no con alternativas de solución. Además cabe considerar que la versión 2014 no trae eso mientras que la última la 2016 sí tiene, esa es la causa de que este tipo de preguntas sean válidas.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza La respuesta puede proveer una explicación... pero no tiene por qué. "¿La herramienta X contiene Y?" se puede responder con un "Sí" o un "No" sin necesidad de explicar nada. Una pregunta que puede ser respondida con un monosílabo es de baja calidad. Que la pregunta trate (ligeramente) sobre programación o una herramienta usada para programar es un requisito para que sea válida, pero no es suficiente para hacerla válida.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si partimos de ese punto hay muchas preguntas de programación hechas aquí que cumplen ese patrón y son válidas para el sitio. Lo que concuerdo contigo es que ese estilo de redacción debe cambiar para que la respuesta no sea un mero sí/no pero en ninguna parte he visto **a nadie** comentando para que se mejore la pregunta, en su lugar solo votan a cierre **sin ningún comentario** con la cruzada de "mantengamos el sitio limpio" cuando la idea central debe ser "ayudemos a las personas a que sus publicaciones sean de calidad"

Comment: Bajo mi último comentario, Pedro favor de actualizar la redacción de la pregunta para que no sea un simple sí/no. De lo contrario, tendría que ser cerrada.

Comment: Pero como me pueden decir si o no, tan solo aquellos que hayan instalado esta versión de SQL Server, inclusive pregunte en el foro de MSDN en la sección de SQL Server y los mismos DBA,s me dijeron que no traía Profiler, eso quiere decir que un simple SI/NO no sería una respuesta valida.

Comment: @PedroÁvila **esto no es el foro de MSDN**. Allí podrán aceptar tus preguntas **bajo sus reglas, aquí NO**. Acabo de editar la pregunta para que luzca con la calidad esperada para el sitio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, no lo incluye

[Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx)

busca en el link "Profiler" y veras que indica que no esta incluido

Pero podrias usar

[ExpressProfiler](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/)

es una muy util alternativa

Comment: Leandro, acabo de instalar SQL Server 2014 Express Edition y si trae Profiler, lo trae desde la version 2012

Comment: estas seguro que instaste una version express ? la verdad es que hace tiempo no uso una distribucion express pero si revisas el link que acabo de agregar en la respuesta, menciona que no lo incluye

Comment: salvo que quizas hayas intalado "SQL Server Express with Tools" quizas este si las incluya

Comment: No es with Toos es with Sp2

Comment: entonces puede ser que lo incluya, si lo has instalado y lo tiene entonces usalo, sino lo incluye podrias suar la alternativa que mencione

Answer (score 2):

Ya se encuentra disponible SQL Server 2016 también, a partir de esta versión la herramienta de administración, SQL Server Management Studio, es una descarga separada, es independiente de la edición que utilices (Express, Developer, Standard, etc.) e incluye el *profiler*.

Puedes descargarla aquí: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: No entiendo cómo esta no es la respuesta aceptada.